# How do I configure a Yongnuo 685 flash to work in TTL with a YN-622 transceiver?

Tags: nikon, flash, off-camera-flash, yongnuo

I have a Nikon D750 and recently purchased a YN-685N and YN-622N transceiver. I can’t seem to configure this combination to use TTL when the flash is off-camera. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. both flash and transceiver are the Nikon versions. When the flash is on camera I get ttl option. On the YN622n it appears I have ttl option to trigger the flash, however when I switch the 685 in radio slave mode I only see to get manual option

Comment: Have you checked that the YN-622N is seated fully forward on the camera hotshoe?

Comment: Just tried it on my older d600 as well. Should it work with the the flash in 622 ext lcd mode and the 622 in ttl type configuration

Comment: Have you checked that the flash and YN-622N are both set to the same radio channel?

Answer (score 1):

There are a variety of things that could cause the setup to not work. It's awfully hard to say what is causing the problem without more details about how the YN-622N and the YN685N are set up.

Things you should check:

- The batteries in the transmitter and in the flash
- The transmitter and flash are both set to the same channel
- The flash should be set to '622 remote' mode. This turns the radio receiver on and disables the flash's hot foot. "622 Remote" wll be displayed across the middle of the flash's LCD screen directly above the power/flash exposure compensation scale. If nothing is displayed above the scale then hold down the 'Mode' button until it comes on.
- The flash is set to the same group as the one you've set the transmitter to control
- Use the test button on the flash to verify the flash is working
- Use the test button on the transmitter to verify it is communicating with the flash
- Set the flash to the 'neutral settings' for manual power (Full 1:1), E-TTL (+/- O FEC), zoom head (Auto), etc. If any other setting is selected for a particular feature, it will override the remote controller for that setting.
- Check that the transmitter is seated properly in the camera's hot shoe. The [following quote](https://www.amazon.com/ask/questions/Tx6B8JO7Z59H6C/ref=ask_al_aap_hza?_encoding=UTF8&sort=helpful) is from a YN-622N-TX user who is using it with a 750D:

> I have a YN-622N-TX on top of my D750 and it works fine(¹)!!!
>
> (¹) Nikon made a slight change to the flash shoe on the D750. It is a bit deeper, so pins don't align quite as easily, however, this is simple to get around. Mount the yn622 on the camera, then lightly tighten the locking wheel. This will extend the alignment pin on the bottom of the yn622. GENTLY pull back on the unit until you hear and/or feel the pin pop into place. Lock it down the rest of the way now. - Rick Moncello